A window suddenly appears and disappears constantly
I have a M1 Pro 2020 and a window appears and disappears suddenly when I'm using my mac. I do my work and suddenly it happens. It happens in a very short time so that I can't recognize. Is there a way you guys know what it is or how to diganose and solve the problem?

Does it happen often enough to capture it in a video recording of the screen?

Is the built-in Firewall enabled? If so, please disable it and see whether there’s a change. Otherwise, start up in Safe Mode and test.

It happens often enough to capture and I'll try. Firstly I'll try firewall thing and let you guys know
